# Isn't there a multidimensional set library in Python?

Tags: python, set

I want to do a multidimensional set compute.
For example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [3, 4, 5, 6]
```

This one's set.difference is:

```
c = a - b
c = [1, 2]
```

But when it's multi-dimensional, I don't know.
How do I do this?

```
a = [['a',1],['b',2],['c',3]]
b = [['a',2],['c',7],['d',5]]
```

I want to calculate around a string.
I wish I could get this value.

```
c = a - b
c = [['b',2]]
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you reverted the formatting I did?

Comment: Do you want the subtraction operation to check only the first value of the internal items?

Comment: `['a',1}` is not valid syntax, the brackets have to match.

Comment: Just a typo....

Comment: Those are lists, not sets. And when you create sets, you can't select the field that's used to compare the elements.

Comment: sorry. Is not code. just text. I just wonder how calculate a multidimensional set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
[i for i in a if i[0] in {str(i[0]) for i in a}.difference({str(i[0]) for i in b})]
```

Output

```
[['b', 2]]
```

This code will return the item that is in the list `a` by the first elements that is not in the `b` list.

Comment: Thanks to you, I have a lot of ways to use it.